# Android:showing a view of an activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

hi i have two activities , first acivity has three icons one is invisible...when i click on the first actitvity it goes to the second activity using intent..my second activity is a login screen ,when the login is success i should come back to first activity  and make an icon visible in the first acitivty..how can i go back to  first activity from second activity and make the icon visible in first one..below is my login screen code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.fyelogin);                    
            etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
            btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
            lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

            final ImageView details = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.red); 

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                    if(password.equals("guest")){
                        lblResult.setText("password successful.");

              // details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    } else {
                        lblResult.setText("password doesn't match.");

                    }                                      
                    finish();}});
```

any suggestions/ help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `startActivityforResult` to open the login activity..then in the `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` in your first activity show the icon..

Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 ...

 static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

 protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
         // When the user center presses, let them pick a contact.
         startActivityForResult(
             new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             new Uri("content://contacts")),
             PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
        return true;
     }
     return false;
 }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             // A contact was picked.  Here we will just display it
             // to the user.
             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, data));
         }
     }
 }
}
```

check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html